# How to create `phpmyadmin` database

Tags: php, mysql, linux, phpmyadmin

How to create `phpmyadmin` database after install phpmyadmin.
It seems like easy.

System:`Ubuntu 14.04 LTS`

I run the command:

```
$sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

I forgot some detail in installing. But I know I was ignore something, because I always enter wrong password.

Now I login to phpmyadmin. I know the `phpmyadmin` database not create in MySQL.
But I don`t know how to fix it.

Please share if you have a solution. My first question here.
Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to install mysql ?

Comment: You don't create a "phpmyadmin database". You create a "MySQL database". phpmyadmin is simply a front-end tool for working with MySQL databases

Comment: Are you talking about the "phpmyadmin" schema is missing after installation ?

Comment: I was install mysql. And phpmyadmin can be logged.i just cant opera CURD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what's the wrong thing you've done installing `phpmyadmin` and `mysql`

If you know the `password` for your `mysql` you can simply purge(delete) your `mysql` and `phpmyadmin` package and install it fresh from following commands.

**To uninstall**

`apt-get purge mysql-server`

`apt-get purge phpmyadmin`

**Install it back again**

`apt-get install mysql-server`

`apt-get install phpmyadmin`

> NOTE: make sure you enter correct mysql password that you used
>   previously while installing.

Comment: thank u so much.I read all content and spend much time when second installing.So many `password` confuse me last time.

Comment: Note that this will remove any MySQL data you have, so if you've already done some database work you'll lose it.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you know your MySQL password, you can just use `dpkg-reconfigure --plow phpmyadmin` to re-run the phpMyAdmin installation process.

It's confusing because "root" is the name of the MySQL administrative account and the completely unrelated system administration account.

Answer (score 0):

`"because I always enter wrong password."`
you need mysql server password not phpmyadmin's. If you don't have a password for mysql, just login in mysql server by root and grant your password.

Answer (score 0):

On Debian 11 (Buster) at least this is what I just discovered:

```
sudo apt install mariadb-server  
sudo mysql -u root -p
> create database phpmyadmin
> grant all privileges on phpmyadmin.* to myuser@localhost identified by 'MY_STRONG_PASSWORD';
> flush privileges;
> quit;
```

If you don't do this you will receive all types of security errors related to blowfish. this is assuming you are going to login with 'myuser' with 'MY_STRONG_PASSWORD'.

Don't install for instance mariadb-server-10.5 since this isn't good when upgrading your machine in the future. The mariadb-server is an alias that will allow a future upgrade/update of the machine to happen smoothly.